# Porting app from Windows Phone Silverlight to Windows 10 - best way

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have windows phone silverlight app with mvvmcross. This app using in-app purchases.  I want to port the application in Windows 10. The best way is probably the creation of universal application for Windows Phone and Windows 10. But I don't have necessary time.I want to realize the transfer in stages:

1. Porting app to Windows 10 with in-app purchases.
2. To implement user authorization in app and data synchronization between applications.
3. Possible upgrade silverlight app to universal app for Windows Phone.

What technology should I choose for stage 1 - WinRt or universal app? If I chose universal app I can not synchronize purchases between applications in the first stage. Synchronize of purchases I can only implement the second phase of the user account. This behavior of the application will not meet the expectations of users. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Windows 10 app, everything is UWP now (choose Universal Windows).

It's probably best to start with a new Windows 10 project and start moving code from you old project to the new one. Most will work. Some need rework. Some XAML definitions are changed, most code should work.

Also have a look at this blogpost with more helpful tips: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/12/17/bring-your-windows-phone-silverlight-apps-to-windows-runtime-xaml-prepare-for-universal-app-development-in-windows-10/

Martin